# Create shift table for string matching in python from pseudo-code

Tags: python, shift

I'm trying to take pseudo-code from my textbook and convert it to a python function. The pseudo-code is for creating a shift table for use with Horspool string matching.

The pseudo-code is as follows:

```
ShiftTable(P[0..m - 1]) 
//Takes input pattern P[0..m-1] and alphabet of possible characters
//Produces output Table[0..size-1] indexed by alphabet's characters and filled with shift sizes computed by formula
     for i = 0 to size - 1 do Table[i] = m
     for j = 0 to m - 2 do Table[P[j]] = m - 1 - j
     return Table
```

My code is as follows:

```
def BuildShiftTable(pattern):
     m = len(pattern)
     alphabet = [i for i in string.ascii_lowercase]
     print(alphabet)
     for i in alphabet:
         table[i] = alphabet[i]
     for j in m - 2:
         table[pattern[j]] = m-1-j
     return table
```

It obviously doesn't work, but I'm trying to understand how to take what the pseudo-code is doing and turn that into working code because I'm not exactly sure what the first for loop in the pseudo-code means by taking size-1 from the Table list if it hasn't been created yet. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

A problem that I see is that you say `for j in m-2`. 'm-2' is an int because 'm' is an int; writing `for j in int` doesn't make much sense. I think you meant to write `for j in range(0,m-2)`.